# How do i solve the java.util.MismatchException in Java?

Tags: java

My lecturer gave us a simple assignment of reading from a text file(as a database) and computing allowances based on age and gender. When I read a line from the txt file, I read each word and stored in a string. But it is a bit confusing for me, what if i have a line in my file say-

```
bucky roberts M 23
```

now i have `firstname = bucky;`  `lastname = roberts;`  `sex = M` and `age = 23`.

Now, based on the above fields if i make a computation, it works fine.

But what if my lecturer says rewrite the same line to be -
`bucky M 23` `firstname = bucky` `lastname = M` `sex = 23`  and `age = null`

Thats how the program reads the line from the file. Now, if i make a if-else statement based on age, i will get an error of `java.util.MismatchException`. How do i resolve this issue and at the same time find a way such that even if my lecturer tempers with the database, the program runs fine. Here is a part of the code below:-

AdultMale.java class:-

```
public class AdultMale extends Male {

    public void getAllowance() {
        readfromFile();
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            firstname = in.next();
            lastname = in.next();
            gender = in.next();
            age = in.nextInt();

            if(gender.equals("M") || gender.equals("Male") || gender.equals("male") ||gender.equals("m"))
            {
                AdultAllowance();

            }

         }
        in.close();

    }       
}
```

Male.java class:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Male extends Members{


        Scanner in;
        public void getAllowance() {

        }

        public void readfromFile()
        {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(new File("Dbase.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void AdultAllowance()
        {
            if(age>=18)
            {
                total = 500;
                total = total + 1000;
                System.out.println(firstname + "\t" +lastname+"\t"+ age + "\t"+ gender+"\t"+total);
                total = 0;
            }

        }

        public void MinorAllowance()
        {
            if(age <18)
            {
                total = 500;
                total = total + 200;
                System.out.println(firstname + "\t"+lastname+"\t" + age + "\t"+ gender+"\t"+total);
                total = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Members class:-

```
public abstract class Members {
            String firstname,lastname,gender;
            int age;
            double total ; 
        }
```

My txt database is called - "Dbase.txt" which contains the following:-

```
Sam     Bell        M   17
Becky   roberts     F   23
Bucky   taylor      M   21
Sammy   lyson       F   16
Terry   gibson      F   23
```

Comment: Can you show us how the file looks like?

Comment: Well, what if your lecturer rewrites this as `Sam 17 M`?.. Is this also possible?.. Also, do you have to use a `Scanner`?. Can you use a `FileReader + BufferedReader?`

Comment: so many `thing`s in a single question :P

Comment: Is the input a single space seperated or a tab seperated?

Comment: problem with `null` in place of `age`.

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Yeah i guess he can write that. My lecturer has a grudge on me and so he can do anything. I have to be well prepared. Bdw, using scanner was the best option for me as i saw that it really worked for me. courtesy @ The New Boston -Bucky Roberts.

Comment: @UmaKanth:-  Tab separated

Comment: @karthik:- Sorry if its confusing.

Comment: @Satya:- I know that age is null. I created that error intentionally so that i can know how to resolve it. Because i am pretty sure that my lecturer will do something crazy like that.

Comment: @MissyZewdie - I just hope that he is not here right now :P.. Anyways.. You could do 2 things.. 1. use methods like `hasNext()` and `hasNextInt()` of `Scanner` to check if you really have a number and name , sex there.. for each String read, check if it is equal to `M` or `F` to ensure that it is just the gender.. So, whatever else is left in the line is your name :). Does that make sense?

Comment: @MissyZewdie - Also use `equalsIgnoreCase("male"`)` instead of `equals()` for different cases

Comment: OP, please rewrite the question in a clear and succinct way instead of commenting. It is terribily confusing otherwise.

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Gotcha! Now, it makes complete sense to me. The lost Mind is awesome. Thanks again. But y is my question downvoted? Is it a bad question or is my code wrong?

Comment: @MissyZewdie- The code was poorly formatted.. the question wasn't exactly bad... Format your code correctly.. and post only code which is related to the question.. Try that and let us know if you have any issues :)

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Thanks a lot. All those downvotes have eaten up my points. I am going to try your suggestions and get back to you in case of any issue. Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Just to be clear the hasnext() and hasnextInt() is supposed to be used here right - firstname = in.next();
            lastname = in.next();
            gender = in.next();
            age = in.nextInt();

Comment: @MissyZewdie - Check my answer.. It works for almost all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the entire line and then use it. So, something like this should work (untested code, written in textpad). This will handle all cases.

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
 for(String str : arr) {
  if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("M") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")); // check for gender for each line in file.
    gender = "M";
    }
  else if(str.matches("\\d+")) { // check for age.
    age = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
  else if(firstName!=null || !firstName.isEmpty()) // for string that is not age or gender.
   {
    firstName = str;
   }
  else{
      lastname = str;
     }
}
}
```

Comment: :- Thanks a lot. Really from the bottom of my heart Thank You.

Comment: :- Yeah it did. Though i am still about to implement the whole code. Can i get back to you if i get stuck anywhere?

Comment: @MissyZewdie :-)  Sure.. Happy coding :)